# Pasting a data on a new Google tab

Tags: python, selenium

I am new in programming (specifically Python Selenium), I have a question regarding pasting a data into an input box, it seems not working if I will paste data on another website, I will received an error. But if I use just one website (either of the two) in pasting the data it is working fine.

Here is my codes below.

[image: Sample error image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Pashu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://tinyurl.com/')


inline_tinysite = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="url"]')
inline_tinysite.send_keys("https://www.teamxtools.com/content/images/project-7/stack-324/exif/2dehands-velgen-volkswagen-golf-7.jpg")
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/input[3]')
submit.click()


driver.execute_script("window.open('https://cutt.ly/', 'new window')")
inline_cuttly = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="link"]')
inline_cuttly.send_keys("https://www.teamxtools.com/content/images/project-7/stack-324/exif/2dehands-velgen-volkswagen-golf-7.jpg")
submit2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div/button')
submit2.click()
#time.sleep(8)
```

Here is the error message as text:

```
C:\Users\Pashu\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Pashu/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/Helloworld.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Pashu/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/Helloworld.py", line 14, in <module>
    inline_cuttly = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="link"]')
  File "C:\Users\Pashu\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Pashu\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Pashu\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Pashu\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="link"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please provide the error message as text.'

Comment: Hi Sir Kindly see original post, i could not paste it here so i just edited the oiginal. :-)

Comment: Pretty clear, no? There is no element matching `//*[@id="link"]`

Comment: But why is it Sir if i run the program with just one website opened it will work? I think the problem is when i open the second tab it could not search for the elements on the second maybe it is searching on the first tab that is why it could not find //*[@id="link"].

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Pashu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://cutt.ly/')

inline_cuttly = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="link"]')
inline_cuttly.send_keys("https://www.teamxtools.com/content/images/project-7/stack-324/exif/2dehands-velgen-volkswagen-golf-7.jpg")
submit2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div/button')
submit2.click()
#time.sleep(8)

Comment: See above modified codes with one website opened, it is working

Comment: I guess i have to answer my question here, finally find out. It is because of the handles, it was stuck on window 1 that is why element //*[@id="link"] is not found. I just added driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) for it to search on the second window. Thats it. :-)

Comment: Post your answer as an actual answer and accept it, or perhaps delete this question if it's unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: Ok Sir Sorry, i am new here. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was stuck on window 1, that is why element `//*[@id="link"]` is not found. I just added

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

for it to search on the second window.